# println no Swift pelo terminal

Tags: ios, compilação, xcode, terminal, swift

Estou tentando compilar uma classe `people.swift` pelo `Terminal` do MacOSX

```
class People
{
    let name:String = ""
    let age:Int = 0

    init(name:String, age:Int)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    let anyPeople = People.init(name:"Jaum", age:23)
    println("O \(anyPeople.name) tem \(anyPeople.age) anos.")
}
```

O comando que estou dando é `./swift -emit-executable people.swift`

Mas está dando o seguinte erro

```
people.swift:13:5: error: expected declaration
    println("O \(anyPeople.name) tem \(anyPeople.age) anos.")
    ^
```

Comment: Eu ainda não estudei swift (tá aqui na minha lista!), mas pode ter código solto assim dentro da classe?

Comment: IMHO [tag:swift-linguagem] me parece terrível. Por que não simplesmente [tag:swift]?

Comment: @helderdarocha Eu tinha criado [tag:swift] mas depois de olhar no SOen vi que eles usam a terminação linguagem nessa tag.

Comment: Já voltei pra tag original que foi criada...

Comment: Eles usam porque lá já havia perguntas sobre a outra linguagem 'swift', que dificilmente alguém vai usar por aqui. Lá também está havendo uma ampla discussão no meta. Pelo jeito que anda deve ficar 'swift' e 'swift-language' como sinônimos.

Comment: Tem uma votação no meta SOen. [tag:swift] está ganhando: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259995/tag-name-poll-swift-apple-swift-or-swift-language?cb=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma classe não é uma estrutura procedural e não pode conter sequencias de instruções para execução a menos que estejam dentro de um método.

As duas últimas linhas do código que você postou referem-se ao uso da classe que você está definindo. No Playground do XCode você pode executar com sucesso o seu código se colocá-las *fora* da classe:

```c
class People {
   ...

}

let anyPeople = People.init(name:"Jaum", age:23)
println("O \(anyPeople.name) tem \(anyPeople.age) anos.")
```

Se você colocar tudo isto dentro de um arquivo `People.swift`, e estiver com o `xcrun` configurado para o XCode6, pode executar no Terminal usando:

```
xcrun swift -i People.swift
```

que vai imprimir:

```
O Jaum tem 23 anos.
```

Se não funcionar pode-ser que o seu XCode Tools não esteja selecionado para o XCode 6. Você pode selecioná-lo usando:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

ou

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

caso esteja utilizando a XCode Beta.

(fonte: https://twitter.com/clattner_llvm/status/474593140511211520)

Comment: É isso mesmo! Uma pequena falta de atenção minha e não vi isso passar.